# raspberry pi display not clear after streaming

Tags: display, android

I installed android on raspberry 3 and when working I have no problem with the display but when streaming a movie display is not clear and picture starts to vibrate. 
thanks for your help

Comment: any movie? or particular resolutions for example 1080p?

Comment: just stream tv program, I change resolution in config.txt file but anything not changed and have problem